# Dependency Injection by type using generics - how does it work?

Tags: java, generics, spring, dependency-injection

Using Spring, I can get all beans of a certain type that are currently defined using this:

```
@Resource
private List<Foo> allFoos;
```

How does Spring do this? I thought type information of generics was erased at runtime. So how does Spring know about the type `Foo` of the list and only inject dependencies of the correct type?

To illustrate: I don't have a bean of type "List" that contains the other beans. Instead, Spring creates that list and adds all beans of the correct type (`Foo`) to this list and then injects that list.

Comment: 1) Type erasure occurs at compile-time, *not* at runtime; 2) all types specified in field and method/constructor parameter declarations are fully preserved in bytecode by the compiler, and are available at runtime through the Java Reflection API. So, Spring does it by obtaining the element type of the `allFoos` field from the corresponding `java.lang.reflect.Field` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all generic information is lost at runtime:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static List<String> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field field = Main.class.getField("list");
        Type type = field.getGenericType();

        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) type;
            Type[] types = pType.getActualTypeArguments();
            for (Type t : types) {
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("not parameterized");
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.String
```